# Multiple groups in mongodb aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I have a collection which contains data like:

```
{
  attribute: 'value',
  date: ISODate("2016-09-20T18:51:05Z")
}
```

and I want to group by `attribute` to get a total count per attribute and at the same time group by `attribute` and `$hour` to get a count per attribute and hour.

I know I can do something like:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$attribute'
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      attribute : '$attribute',
      hour: {
        '$hour' : '$date'
      }
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      attribute: '$_id.attribute'
    },
    hours: {
      '$push': {
        hour: '$_id.hour',
        count: '$count'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to get both results in two separate aggregations, but is there a way to get the result I want in one query?

Edit as requested:

Perhaps this is **utterly wrong** but ideally I would like to get a response like:

```
{
  _id: "attribute1",
  total: 20, // Total number of attribute1 documents

  // And the breakdown of those 20 documents per hour
  hours: [{
    hour: 10,
    count: 8
  },
  {
    hour: 14,
    count: 12
  }]
}
```

However the whole point of the question is whether this can be done (and how) on one query in mongodb. Not in two queries that would be merged on the application layer

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you provide a concrete example of the output you're thinking about?

Comment: @LeifEricson I've added an example response, I hope it's clear now. English is not my native language so there might a language gap here as well, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group by attribute-hour pairs and their corresponding occurrences.
Then, you project the attribute, a pair of hour-count, and a copy of that count.
Finally, you group by the attribute alone, `$push` the pairs, and sum the counts.

```
[
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                attribute: "$attribute",
                hour: { "$hour": "$date" }
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            attribute: "$_id.attribute",
            pair: { hour: "$_id.hour", count: "$count" },
            count: "$count",
            _id: 0
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$attribute",
            hours: {
                $push: "$pair"
            },
            total: {
                $sum: "$count"
            }
        }
    }
]
```